# how to delete a target game object on collision with a different object in unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to make object **A** self-destruct if object **A** collides with object **B** but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

I was wondering if anyone could help?

Answer (score 3):

You must use [OnCollisionEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html)

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll){
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

you can add a condition to check with which gameobject collided.

Comment: Or `OnCollisionEnter` if OP is working with 3D colliders. Also as pointed out by the documentation the parameter can be left out in this case, since it is unused (and avoids unnecessary calculations)